Is this a paradox or a mistake?
Zhang Hong recently asked "is there a paradox lurking in Godel's 1931 incompleteness proof" (paraphrase)? This can be answered in two ways: First, by proving quite generally that there are no paradoxes in mathematical logic. Or, second, by actually producing a paradoxical result within mathematical logic.
The following is putatively an answer of the second kind, to Hong's question.  I'm posting here to ask, "is the following a paradox, or just a mistake?"

Let #Q# be the Godel number of the expression, Q.
Let @r@ be the expression corresponding to the Godel number, r.
Now let n = #@n@ --> P#, with P being arbitrary.
Then P.

(Note that Q = @#Q#@ and r = #@r@#, for all expressions, Q, and all Godel numbers, r.)
The proof from 3 to 4 goes this way: Suppose @n@. Then by applying @..@ quotes to both sides of 3, it follows that @n@ --> P. So it follows that P (by modus ponens). Suppose ~@n@, contrariwise. Then @n@ --> P is false. So the antecedent is true and the conclusion is false. Thus it follows that @n@ (since this is the antecedent). And it follows from this that @n@ --> P. So we have it again (by modus ponens) that P. So, whether @n@ is true or false, it yeilds a proof that P, even though P could be anything.
Edit:  It was suggested that I add a link to Zhang Hong's question.  So here it is:  Hong's question.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I want to register my alarm at the way this question has been treated.  Beside the objections of user58697 and Bumble, which are based on a use/mention conflation, there have been no other critical notes.  And yet the question is downvoted to -3.  More, the question has today been closed with the declaration that it is off-topic.  But according to the definition displayed, off-topic questions "push a personal philosopy" -- my question does not do this.  Further, my question is answerable.

I'm sure nobody intends this, but I feel like I'm being censored in order to hide a secret.  Lol.

@JamesKing If you need help understanding why the question is off-topic, or believe it's on-topic and would like it to be reopened, you can ask on Meta.

@n@ is an expression which Godel number is n. @n@ --> P is a different expression, so its Godel number is different. Therefore, there is no such n for which the equation n = #@n@ --> P# may hold.

I have three contraries to present: (1) Within the equation @n@ --> P, we can regard @n@ simply as a string of the basic symbols of the language, and not as anything like a metalinguistic function which must be resolved before the overall equation can be seen.  Seeing it this way, the equation involves no circularity.
Now, @n@ is an expression which resolves_to (not 'is') the expression with Godel number n.  @n@ is like a name for an expression; it is not the expression itself.  '@n@ --> P', conceived syntactically is another name.

If that doesn't confound you, consider this:  (2) A very similar solution can be given just in consideration that a numeral is not it's number.  (3) Also: The  fixed point lemma seems to provide that such an n must exist -- after all, both the @..@ and #..# functions are computable.

You see, whatever mysteries there are concerning what @n@ may be, '@n@' is just an expression.  We can compute a value for #@n@ --> P#.  And we can set n to take that value.  So then it follows that n = #@n@ --> P#.  What's the problem?
